# jquery Iframe src attribute

Tags: jquery, iframe, attributes

Why does x alerts undefined for iframe but works for embed. I'm grabbing the iframe or embed code from a textarea

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9kiWvkj2ldWiU?hd=1"></iframe>

var textarea = $('#embedModal textarea'),
textareaValue = textarea.val(),
$embed = $($(textareaValue).find('iframe')),
x = $embed.attr('src');
alert(x); //alerts undefined for iframe
```

If you change find('iframe') to find('embed') and you try with the below embed code. then i'm able to get the value of src, but with iframe i get undefined. Seems strange.

```
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9kiWvkj2ldWiU?hd=1"></embed>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. find('iframe') is not really needed. it works without.

Answer (score 0):

Iframe and embed are not the same tag, why would you be able to find them both with the same selector.

Comment: i'm just grabbing the attribute and not doing anything special

Answer (score 0):

If your iframe is for a different domain, the browser will block any interaction between its contents and your Javascript. This cross-domain separation is to prevent phishing and the like.